# Images take place but doesn't appear in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-image

When I try to add an image to my first react native application it doesn't appear even if it take place.

I did like the documentation said but the problem still exists

here's my code:

```
<Image source={{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
  resizeMode="stretch" style={{
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 75
  }}/>
```

I used require for local images and also the same:

```
<Image source={require('./images/item7.jpg')}
  resizeMode="stretch" style={{
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 75
  }}/>
```

Comment: Try giving the property of flex: 1 to your style in Image.

Comment: The same problem. @Atin Singh

Comment: I just tried to reach out the Uri that you mentioned in the source attribute and it says the page doesn't exist.

Comment: `https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png` is not an image.

Comment: I tried other images and I faced the same problem and in my question I said I tried also the local and nothing changed.